# Div button to toggle divs - Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, toggle

I'm trying to add a "back button" which will toggle the current div to the previous div. Basically, I have a div of an Oklahoma map which fills the window. When the user clicks a certain area of the map, the div is toggled with a div that is the image of the "zoomed-in" area which they selected. I want my back button to appear on top of this zoomed-in div, in the bottom right corner, and if the user clicks the button, the div will be toggled with the original Oklahoma map div.

Here's the code I've tried so far:

CSS:

```
#backButton
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    right:50px;
    background:url('images/backspace.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    z-index:2;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
.button
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100px;
    right:100px;
    background:url('images/backspace.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    z-index:2;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="backButton" style="display:none; background:url('images/backspace.png');" onClick="#container.toggle();">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

---

The button appears correctly, but it isn't functioning. I'm sure it has to do with `onClick="#container.toggle();"` but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Just for background information, the *container* is the original Oklahoma map and it is toggled off in my JS code (`$("#container").toggle();`) when I switch to a zoomed-in div.

**EDIT:** Ok, so I do have Jquery and I tried making a click event like my other toggle events:

```
 $("#backButton").click(function(e)
{
    $("#container").toggle();
            $("#backButton").toggle();
});
```

**-->** I removed the onClick part in the div. The button will toggle off when I click it, but the container div (Oklahoma map) is not toggling back on.

Comment: I think you may be mixing up JS syntax with jQuery syntax. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: If you're using jquery, why are you using the onClick tag? You should use $("#backButton").click(function() {}) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using jQuery (evident in your code)

Put this in your javascript:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#backButton").toggle();// hide the div (assume you have it turned on somewhere
  $("#container").toggle();) // show the other div
});
```

remove the `onClick="#container.toggle();"` from the markup

Comment: Just an FYI, I REALLY don't like the ID names of "button" and "backButton" for the divs, especially the first one.

Comment: What would you have the ID names be?

Comment: I would tend to not use "button" because it is the same as an element name - prefix it with "turnOffButton" or "zoomOffButton" etc. The "backButton" I would make a "zoomOffButtonContainer" - as more descriptive.

Comment: Would you know why the container is not toggling back on while the button is toggling off? See under the **EDIT** in my question.

Comment: I found out why it wasn't toggling on; I _do_ need to toggle off the zoomed-in div. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You want your onClick method to call a valid function such as `abcMethod()`. (Wherever your toggle code lives).